# How to go about a d-smooth sequence algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sequence, seq

I'm really struggling to design an algorithm to find d, which is the lowest value that can be added or subtracted (at most) to make a given sequence strictly increasing.

For example.. say seq[] = [2,4,8,3,1,12]

given that sequence, the algorithm should return "5" as d because you can add or subtract at most 5 to each element such that the function is strictly increasing.

I've tried several approaches and can't seem to get a solid technique down.

I've tried looping through the seq. and checking if seq[i] < seq[i+1]. If not, it checks if d>0.. if it is, try to add/subtract it from seq[i+1]. Otherwise it calculates d by taking the difference of seq[i-1] - seq[i].

I can't get it to be stable though and Its like I keep adding if statements that are more "special cases" for unique input sequences. People have suggested using a binary search approach, but I can't make sense of applying it to this problem.

Any tips and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

### Here's my code in progress - using Python - v4

```
def ComputeMaxDelta3(seq):
    # Create a copy to speed up comparison on modified values
    aItems = seq[1:] #copies sequence elements from 1 (ignores seq[0])
    # Will store the fix values for every item
    # this should allocate 'length' times the 0 value
    fixes = [0] * len(aItems)
    print("fixes>>",fixes)

    # Loop until no more fixes get applied
    bNeedFix = True
    while(bNeedFix):
        # Hope will have no fix this turn
        bNeedFix = False

        # loop all subsequent item pairs (i should run from 0 to length - 2)
        for i in range(0,len(aItems)-1):
            # Left item
            item1 = aItems[i]
            # right item
            item2 = aItems[i+1]

            # Compute delta between left and right item
            # We remember that (right >= left + 1
            nDelta = item2 - (item1 + 1)
            if(nDelta < 0):
                # Fix the right item
                fixes[i+1] -= nDelta
                aItems[i+1] -= nDelta
                # Need another loop
                bNeedFix = True

    # Compute the fix size (rounded up)
    # max(s) should be int and the division should produce an int
    nFix = int((max(fixes)+1)/2)
    print("current nFix:",nFix)
    

    # Balance all fixes
    for i in range(len(aItems)):
        fixes[i] -= nFix

    print("final Fixes:",fixes)
    print("d:",nFix)
    print("original sequence:",seq[1:])
    print("result sequence:",aItems)

    return
```

---

### Here's whats displayed:

```
Working with: [6, 2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 12] 
    [0]= 6 So the following numbers are the sequence: 
         aItems = [2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 12] 

fixes>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
current nFix: 6
final Fixes: [-6, -6, -6, 0, 3, -6]
d: 1
original sequence: [2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 12]
result sequence: [2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 12]

d SHOULD be: 5

done!
```

### ~Note~

I start at 1 rather than 0 due to the first element being a key

Comment: I see you are using ceil when computing nFix, but still adding 1. I don't know python, but in my code I purposely added 1 to get the same effect of ceil with int value, thus avoiding converting to float. Then, if max(s)/2 returns a floating value (that is not in c#) you should ceil without incrementing.

Comment: I just added my test code for you to check its results.

Comment: @Rubidium37 I just copied/pasted my code and removed the +1 in the ceil. But I get d=20 and negative numbers in the new sequence. It generated: [-24, -22, -18, -11, 5, 26]

Comment: I saw right now some mistakes in your python version... You don't declare variable "fixes" and rather declare variable "s" assigning "aItems", but without cloning it, as instead I did. Then, you decrease "s" and "aItems", that probably point to the same array items, but my "fixes" was intended to start all zero and hold the deltas.

Comment: Tomorrow morning I will post your python code rectified in order to work as my C# version. Please try it as soon as possible.

Comment: You are amost there, but I see two mistakes (one I should have noticed before, sorry):   1) you wrote "nFix = int((max(aItems)+1)/2)" instead of "nFix = int((max(fixes)+1)/2)";   2) "print("d:",nDelta)" must be replaced with "print("d:",nFix)".   Hope these corrections will finally give you the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As anticipated, here is (or should be) the Python version of my initial solution:

```
def ComputeMaxDelta(aItems):
    # Create a copy to speed up comparison on modified values
    aItems = aItems[:]
    # Will store the fix values for every item
    # this should allocate 'length' times the 0 value
    fixes = [0] * len(aItems)

    # Loop until no more fixes get applied
    bNeedFix = True
    while(bNeedFix):
        # Hope will have no fix this turn
        bNeedFix = False

        # loop all subsequent item pairs (i should run from 0 to length - 2)
        for i in range(0,len(aItems)-1):
            # Left item
            item1 = aItems[i]
            # right item
            item2 = aItems[i+1]

            # Compute delta between left and right item
            # We remember that (right >= left + 1
            nDelta = item2 - (item1 + 1)
            if(nDelta < 0):
                # Fix the right item
                fixes[i+1] -= nDelta
                aItems[i+1] -= nDelta
                # Need another loop
                bNeedFix = True

    # Compute the fix size (rounded up)
    # max(s) should be int and the division should produce an int
    nFix = (max(fixes)+1)/2 # corrected from **(max(s)+1)/2**

    # Balance all fixes
    for i in range(len(s)):
        fixes[i] -= nFix

    print("d:",nFix) # corrected from **print("d:",nDelta)**
    print("s:",fixes)

    return
```

I took your Python and fixed in order to operate exactly as my C# solution.
I don't know Python, but looking for some reference on the web, I should have found the points where your porting was failing.

If you compare your python version with mine you should find the following differences:

1. You saved a reference **aItems** into **s** and used it as my **fixes**, but **fixes** was meant to start as all 0.
2. You didn't cloned **aItems** over itself, then every alteration to its items was reflected outside of the method.
3. Your for loop was starting at index 1, whereas mine started at 0 (the very first element).
4. After the check for **nDelta** you subtracted **nDelta** from both **s** and **aItems**, but as I stated at points 1 and 2 they were pointing to the same items.
5. The **ceil** instruction was unnedeed because the division between two integers produces an integer, as with C#.

Please remember that I fixed the Python code basing my knowledge only on online documentation, because I don't code in that language, so I'm not 100% sure about some syntax (my main doubt is about the **fixes** declaration).

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: Thanks! definitely starting to make more sense. I still can't implement it right though. So fixes should be initialized as the size of aItems, with each element set to 0? I'm going to try and fix the syntax and I'll update my code again.

Comment: Yes: fixes start filled with 0, because during the loop its values will be decreased based on differences between corresponding aItems values (read nDelta). After getting the max from fixes, all of its items get lowered by nFix, so every value still 0 will become -nFix and any value equal to the max one will become (about) nFix: this way fixes array will contain values between -nFix and nFix.

Comment: Ok. I think I fixed some of the syntax so Ill update my code on here and post the display results. Python starts w/ index 0 and ends with index length-1. So "in range(len(aItems)) would loop 0-9 if there were 10 elements. I start with the second element because for my prompt, the first element is supposed to be the number of items being put in the list. So if aList[0]=6, it means the list will have 7 elements but only aList[1] through aList[len-1] count towards solving the problem.

Comment: About the first element, I now understand: it was not clear to me before. However I don't understand why you have the count as first element: len(aItems) already should give you that value. Anyway, given this constraint, you should not only start loops from 1 but also decrease by 1 both len(aItems) and len(fixes) everywhere they are used.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. I updated my progress and added the shell display. It looks like the sequence is increasing properly, but the d is off.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! I have it working now for most cases. One test that is giving me an issue is aItems = [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8], which should give d=4, but its giving d=3. Any idea why?

Comment: Uhm.. A kind of case I didn't test before, but with the C# code it is returning 4, as expected. I guess it is something with "nFix = int((max(fixes)+1)/2)". If you can print/dump the contents of fixes before this line, you should find them as [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. If that is the case, then the problem is with "max/2" rounding, because max should return 7, that increased by 1 becomes 8 and divided by 2 becomes 4.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah if I print it right before the nFix= line, i get [0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]. And where my code prints "final fixes:" it shows [-3, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: Then the main for loop is skipping the first item. Try changing the line "for i in range(0,len(aItems)-1):" to "for i in range(0,len(aItems)):", althought it should be already ok because "range(0,len(aItems)-1)" should produce [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be of help. Let me know if you encounter other problems with this algorithm.

Comment: Where would I place an accumulator to count the number of comparisons?

Comment: If you want to count how many times nDelta get computed and compared to 0 (regardless of the comparison outcome) then you should declare the counter outside of the while loop and increment it just before the "if(nDelta < 0)"

Comment: Awesome, thanks once again! I think I just have one final question. How would I go about analyzing the algorithms run time?

Comment: I guess you want to measure the time taken by the method execution. I don't know how you can do it in Python: it depends on the programming environment and the running operating system. The right way in C# (and .Net) is through StopWatch class, that provide StartNew and Stop methods to record the CPU ticks before and after any operation and then compute their difference. If you need it in Python, I suggest you to open a new question to allow any expert to reply to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
public static int ComputeMaxDelta(int[] aItems, out int[] fixes)
{
    // Create a copy to speed up comparison on modified values
    aItems = (int[])aItems.Clone();
    // Will store the fix values for every item
    fixes = new int[aItems.Length];

    // Loop until no more fixes get applied
    var bNeedFix = true;
    while (bNeedFix)
    {
        // Hope will have no fix this turn
        bNeedFix = false;

        // loop all subsequent item pairs
        for (int ixItem = 0; ixItem < aItems.Length - 1; ixItem++)
        {
            // Left item
            var item1 = aItems[ixItem];
            // right item
            var item2 = aItems[ixItem + 1];

            // Compute delta between left and right item
            // We remember that (right >= left + 1)
            var nDelta = item2 - (item1 + 1);
            if (nDelta < 0)
            {
                // Fix the right item
                fixes[ixItem + 1] -= nDelta;
                aItems[ixItem + 1] -= nDelta;
                //Need another loop
                bNeedFix = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Compute the fix size (rounded up)
    var nFix = (fixes.Max() + 1) / 2;

    // Balance all fixes
    for (int ixItem = 0; ixItem < aItems.Length; ixItem++)
        fixes[ixItem] -= nFix;

    return nFix;
}
```

The function returns the maximum computed fix gap.
As a bounus, the parameter fixes will receive the fixes for every item. These are the delta to apply to each source value in order to be sure that they will be in ascending order: some fix can be reduced but some analysis loop is required to achieve that optimization.

---

The following is a code to test the algorithm. If you set a breakpoint at the end of the loop, you'll be able to check the result for sequence you provided in your example.

```
var random = new Random((int)Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());
for (int ixLoop = -1; ixLoop < 100; ixLoop++)
{
    int nCount;
    int[] aItems;

    // special case as the provided sample sequence
    if (ixLoop == -1)
    {
        aItems = new[] { 2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 12 };
        nCount = aItems.Length;
    }
    else
    {
        // Generates a random amount of items based on my screen's width
        nCount = 4 + random.Next(21);
        aItems = new int[nCount];
        for (int ixItem = 0; ixItem < nCount; ixItem++)
        {
            // Keep the generated numbers below 30 for easier human analysis
            aItems[ixItem] = random.Next(30);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("***");
    Console.WriteLine("  # " + GetText(Enumerable.Range(0, nCount).ToArray()));
    Console.WriteLine("    " + GetText(aItems));

    int[] aFixes;
    var nFix = ComputeMaxDelta(aItems, out aFixes);

    // Computes the new values, that will be always in ascending order
    var aNew = new int[aItems.Length];
    for (int ixItem = 0; ixItem < aItems.Length; ixItem++)
    {
        aNew[ixItem] = aItems[ixItem] + aFixes[ixItem];
    }

    Console.WriteLine("  = " + nFix.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  ! " + GetText(aFixes));
    Console.WriteLine("  > " + GetText(aNew));
}
```

---

Regards,
Daniele.

Comment: Hmm. I tried replicating it, but I don't think its correct. Its giving d=6 [2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 12] which means the 1 got unchanged

Comment: In my test program it computes 5. But even if it would be 6, you know that 1+6 produces 7 and, even if not needed 12-4 produces 8. Then I'm sure the function works as expected. Tell me how you replicated it, because I think something could be wrong in the replication.

Comment: Hmm i retried implementing it and its calculating larger numbers. I tried it in python, Ill add my code in my question.